# Model wont join Rigged Bones

Tags: rigging, bones

I do not know how to be more basic or too the point than this.

I got the model, and i made the rigging for the model. So the rigging/bones are aligned with the model/character.

I should be able to drop the model/character into the armature and select automatic weights, wait a minute and be done so i can start posing and animation creation.

NOPE.

I tried removing and adding modifiers, I tried using a different model. I made the rigging from scratch. So why wont nothing link with the armatures!

Comment: Can you frame your question in a more focused manner?  The way it is written now comes off more like a complaint.

Answer (score 0):

In *object mode* select the character, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the armature, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and choose automatic weights.
Apply rotation and scale to both objects before parenting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

The automatic weights will work properly only if the mesh is consistent, no spare parts or loose pieces, no double vertices, manifold.
Apply mirror modifiers also.

Comment: did all this, and before Blender updated I did create a couple models that had no problems being dragged into and accepting Armature . However, now nothing works to allow for this and I would appreciate a link to a current video for the 2.78 version so i can observe and follow it t see if i can find where the problem has come to be.

Comment: I think you should upload your .blend file, to get analized.